# str.encode() giving unexpected results

Tags: python, character-encoding

I've been playing around with python built-ins and have gotten some confusing (for me) results.

Take a look at this code:

```
>>> 'ü'.encode()
b'\xc3\xbc'
```

Why was `\xc3\xbc` (195 and 188 in decimal) returned? If you look at the [ascii table](https://theasciicode.com.ar/), we see that `ü` is the 129'th character. Or if you take a look [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/00FC/), we see that `ü` is the 252'nd Unicode character, which is what you get from

```
>>> ord('ü')
252
```

So where is the `\xc3\xbc` coming from and why is it split up into two bytes? and when you decode: `b'\xc3\xbc'.decode()`, how does it know that these two bytes are for one character?

Comment: It's only unexpected because you don't know how [UTF-8 works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Comment: The fact that someone is on StackOverflow asking a question means that they don't know how something works.

Comment: @DanielWalker good point.  I originally thought the poster knew that `encode` was generating UTF-8, but in re-reading the question I can see that's not the case.

Comment: @MarkRansom that's why I said `and have gotten some confusing (for me) results.` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the table you're looking at, you're looking at the section titled "Extended ASCII", more commonly known at [ISO/IEC 8859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859), or latin1. ASCII, as a character set, defines 7-bit characters from 0 to 127. latin1 defines the other 128 single-byte characters and is an extension of ASCII. Python uses UTF-8, which extends ASCII (and hence is compatible with it) but is incompatible with latin1.

The character ü is has Unicode codepoint 0xFC (252 in decimal) and, when using UTF-8, is encoded using two characters.

Lots of online ASCII tables get this wrong. It's inaccurate to call the code points 128 up to 255 ASCII characters, because ASCII doesn't claim to assign *any* value to those code points.

Comment: When you say `when using UTF-8, is encoded using two characters`, is that supposed to explain the where the `\xbc\xbc` came from?

Comment: Yes, the byte string consists of two bytes: 195 and 188 (in hexadecimal, that's 0xC3 and 0xBC). The specifics of how that relates to the code point 252 are really just a bunch of bitwise arithmetic and you can read all about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: Exactly.  If you pass `'latin-1'` as the argument to `encode`, you'll get what you're after.

Comment: UTF-8 efficiently encodes ASCII characters (0-127) as single bytes.  Last I checked UNICODE now has characters up to 0x10FFFD.  It clearly cannot encode every character uniquely with 1 byte.  3 bytes per character would work, but is inefficient.  The most common characters are encoded with one byte, but some bytes have to be reserved to indicate additional bytes follow.  254 could indicate 2 more bytes follow, 255 could indicate 3 additional bytes follow, but that would make the codes 3 and 4 bytes long respectively.  The compromise is to use more bytes as multi byte codes prefixes.